# Undefined references when linking with Lua compiled from source?

Tags: gcc, lua, static-linking

Downloaded `lua5_1_4_Sources.tar.gz` and compiled liblua.a from source using TDM-GCC 4.5.1.

Everything compiled fine:

```
Linking ..
  ar rcs liblua.a 5.1.4/src/lapi.o 5.1.4/src/lauxlib.o 5.1.4/src/lbaselib.o 5.1.4/src/lcode.o 5.1.4/src/ldblib.o 5.1.4/s rc/ldebug.o 5.1.4/src/ldo.o 5.1.4/src/ldump.o 5.1.4/src/lfunc.o 5.1.4/src/lgc.o 5.1.4/src/linit.o 5.1.4/src/liolib.o 5.1 .4/src/llex.o 5.1.4/src/lmathlib.o 5.1.4/src/lmem.o 5.1.4/src/loadlib.o 5.1.4/src/lobject.o 5.1.4/src/lopcodes.o 5.1.4/s rc/loslib.o 5.1.4/src/lparser.o 5.1.4/src/lstate.o 5.1.4/src/lstring.o 5.1.4/src/lstrlib.o 5.1.4/src/ltable.o 5.1.4/src/ ltablib.o 5.1.4/src/ltm.o 5.1.4/src/lua.o 5.1.4/src/luac.o 5.1.4/src/lundump.o 5.1.4/src/lvm.o 5.1.4/src/lzio.o 5.1.4/sr c/print.o 5.1.4/src/wmain.o
```

Compiled example source just fine:
http://pastebin.com/EGvMRjth

Tried to link:

```
Compiling..
  g++ test.o -g -shared -Lshared/build/lua -llua -o libtest.so
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `lua_tonumber(lua_State*, int)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `lua_pushnumber(lua_State*, double)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `lua_tonumber(lua_State*, int)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `lua_pushnumber(lua_State*, double)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `lua_pushcclosure(lua_State*, int (*)(lua_State*), int)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `lua_setfield(lua_State*, int, char const*)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `lua_pushcclosure(lua_State*, int (*)(lua_State*), int)'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `lua_setfield(lua_State*, int, char const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm trying to follow the examples from here:

http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm

Comment: Are you compiling C++? You should use `extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
};`

Comment: I must be blind. I even read the documentation which said to include `lua.hpp` for C++ (which includes the extern "C"). Whoops! Resubmit as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments..
It seems you are compiling C++ and the Lua version you use is probably coded in C.
This means you need to include either the `lua.hpp` or if not available you need to include the libraries by using `extern "C"` like so:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
};
```